# Bootstrap Grid: HTML Element Larger Than Body @ 100%

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've read and implemented quite a few solutions to this problem as it seems to be a pretty common frustrating experience. I'm setting two bootstrap columns to 100% because I want them to fill the available space on the page, but instead of filling the body they fill the html element...which is larger than the body. If I don't have these columns set to 100% then there isn't a visible issue, and if I make it so I don't see the overflow then everything is close to perfect...but that's clearly a bad practice. My basic layout is this (it's in HAML):

```
%head
  %meta stuff
  = csrf_meta_tag
%body#dashboard
  = yield 
%footer.clearfix.dashboard-footer
  .aaux.footer-links
    %a stuff
= javascript_include_tag "application"
```

My partial page looks like this:

```
.clearfix.tabs
  = link_to "View All", dashboard_patients_path, class: "active", method: :get
  = link_to "Add Patient", dashboard_patients_add_path, method: :get
.col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-8.col-lg-8.left-side
  .row
    .clearfix.title Something
    .table-responsive
      %table.table.table-striped
        %thead
          %tr
            %td stuff
        %tbody
          - @stuff.each do |stuff|
            %tr
              - simple logic
              %td stuff
    .clearfix.buttons-div
      = paginate @variable
.col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-4.col-lg-4.right-side
```

My relevant CSS (minus the bootstrap stuff) is

```
html
  padding: 0 0 0 0
  margin: 0 0 0 0

body
  background-color: #000000
  background-image: image-url("bg.png")
  background-repeat:  no-repeat
  background-size: cover
  position: relative
  min-height: 69em
  height: 100vh
  padding: 0 0 0 0
  margin: 0 0 0 0



.left-side
    min-height: 600px
    position: relative
    .title
      margin: 30px 0 20px 5%
      font-size: 35px
      font-family: 'aaux'
      color: #84878C
    .table
      border: 1px solid #BBBBBB
      font-size: 27px
      font-family: 'aaux'
      color: #84878C
      margin: 0 5% 70px
      width: 90%
      thead
        background: #BECAD9
      tbody td
        border: 0
        background: #FAFAFA
```

I'd appreciate any and all suggestions; I'm still working my way through the myriad of solutions for similar problems on Stackoverflow but seeing as I'm coming up on my third hour I thought it time to ask for some insight to my specific situation.

Comment: columns go inside rows, not the other way around

Comment: Changing that definitely helped solve the immediate problem, thanks! The two columns are now within the row element, and the body and html are the correct size. Setting the row to 100% then caused a similar problem of overflow, which was the result of (I believe) my nav bar. So I set it to 85% and everything worked perfectly after ensuring that none of the elements had excessive margins or padding.  Just in case anyone else ran into this :) Thanks again, slynagh!

Comment: The 85% solution requires also making sure the nav bar components are set to percentages.